# LDO that doesn't drop out?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, ldo

I have a scenario where my Vin is 12VDC and my (small inductive) load is 7VDC.

I need a voltage regulator that would satisfy following conditions:

1. if the Vin > 7VDC + Vdropout, then Vout = 7VDC
2. if Vin < 7VDC + Vdropout, then Vout = Vin.

In other words, I want it not to drop out, but instead to feed whatever lower voltage there is to the load. I.e.:
if Vin == 5.5VDC, then Vout = 5.5VDC (or 5.2Vdc - not important)

I was planning to use UCC283-ADJ, but I can't figure out how to keep regulator open during voltage drop or brownout.

Comment: Your description is not consistent. At one point you say if Vin < (7V+dropout) then Vout=Vin, but then you say if Vin = 5.5V the Vout should be 5.5V - Vdropout. What do you expect to happen to Vout if Vin is (7V + dropout) **plus a little noise**? The output will be jumping between 7V and Vin.

Comment: LDO has a BJT in serial. Minimum drop 0.3V.  Try switching DC-DC.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I just fixed my question. the voltage drop after Vin < Vout + Vdropout is not important. Even if Vin == 5.5V and Vout == 5.2V - it's ok too.

Comment: Your definition of dropout is wrong. Dropout doesn't mean the LDO stops passing current to the output. It just means the LDO stops regulating.

Comment: Ok, I had it all wrong in my head. Thanks for clarification!

Comment: You didn't specify the load current(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want Vin to be passed directly to Vout when not regulating, in which case you need to look for regulator that doesn't have low voltage cutoff (UVLO), where the regulator will shutoff if Vin is below certain level. As Kevin mentions, you'll still have a drop from Vin to Vout, but that might be acceptable.

Comment: No UVLO is what I was asking. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Most LDOs do similar to what you describe except that when the input goes below the programed Vout + dropout, 7V in your case, the output continues to be the input minus the dropout voltage.

The dropout of the UCC283 at 1.5A output is typically 200mV so at 7V input the output voltage would be 6.8V.

If you want to reclaim that last 200mV you would need a mechanism to bypass the regulator altogether. You could then have the problem that @Elliot Anderson describes in the comments where the output could jump between the two voltages in an undesirable fashion.

There are buck-boost switching regulators that can do what you describe - they either step down or can step-up when the input is too low.

In one case I implemented a system with a boost converter to provide 6V to an LDO configured to provide 5V. At input levels above 6V the boost converter would pass through with a diodes drop and as the voltage went below 6V it would start boosting. At all times the LDO would have at least 6V input and so could reliably provide 5V output whether the input voltage was 3V or 9V.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with a **RELAY** allows and tracks the input voltage all the way to 0 (zero) volts, with practically no voltage drop.

You simply add a relay whose contacts go across the regulator, and are normally closed (NC) if the solenoid is not energized, but kept open by the solenoid while the voltage is above certain level.
Here is an example schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmyi79.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the input voltage is above the zener voltage plus the V<sub>BE</sub>, the transistor and thus relay is on, the relay contacts are open, and the regulator determines the output voltage.

Once the voltage drops below the zener+V<sub>BE</sub>, the transistor and the relay turn off, letting the relay contacts fall back and make a short across the regulator, making the output voltage follow the input voltage.

The downside to this solution is the zener + relay solenoid currents which represent a small power loss and inefficiency, but if you can "live with them", this is your solution.

If you need a more accurate switching circuit instead o the zener and transistor, you could use an op-amp, a voltage reference and 2 resistors in a voltage-divider configuration.

Finally, the relay solenoid should be rated for 5-6V and a low current in order to waste less power AND to prevent damaging currents when the input voltage is much higher than 5V (such as 12V in your question).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, regulators do not work that way. That's why they're called voltage converters (or power converters). Since what you're looking for is to "short" your Vin to your Vout below a certain minimum voltage, then you must employ a Power Mux.

A Power Mux is different than a regular mux because they can conduct high currents. Therefore, I'd recommend looking for either of the following:

1. LDO with built-in power mux
2. Buck with built-in power mux
3. Power Mux. You can have the control signal be the UVLO or have a comparator check your voltage levels.